# Dynamic sheet name in formula

Tags: google-sheets

`sheet1` and `sheet2` are structured the same way.

In `sheet3` I'm using the `sumproduct()` this way:

`=SOMMEPROD((**sheet1**!$C$2:$C$2000=$A3)*(**sheet1**!$B$2:$B$2000=D$2)*(**sheet1**!$D$2:$D$2000=$B3)*(**sheet1**!$E$2:$E$2000=$C3)*(**sheet1**!$I$2:$I$2000="Ongoing"))`

Is there a way to replace the hardcoded `sheet1` in my formula above by referring to a cell which correspond to the name of the sheet?

Comment: Here is a simple example of the result I want. Sheet3 column C, I would like to dynamise the sheet name in the formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JwEzkl8zxvk6ZX4zLixxuAXNYtgRomtQeh1mFJou73s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 20):

You can insert the cell values but will need to use [=INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) to make them behave the way you expect.

I built a simple example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ot-jrPJ_C5sKskHd4zMZsLCG8xgduchDk0X270J0n1Q/edit#gid=1128802724).

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A3")&(B1&"!A3")
```

This formula gets the page name from cells A1 and B1 on the page the formula is on and uses them to references the cell A3 on the two other pages named in those cells.

For your particular formula . . .

If you want to make sheet1 dynamic, you need to pull the value from somewhere. Let's assuming it's in cell A1 on the sheet where the formula resides. Set the value of cell A1 to be the name of the sheet you wish to use.

I didn't check the last portion but I think I escaped the quotes correctly.

```
=SOMMEPROD((INDIRECT(A1&"!$C$2:$C$2000=$A3"))((INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$2:$B$2000=D$2"))((INDIRECT(A1&"!$D$2:$D$2000=$B3"))((INDIRECT(A1&"!$E$2:$E$2000=$C3"))((INDIRECT(A1&"!$I$2:$I$2000=\"Ongoing\"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I also did a concrete example as I don't see how I can do what I want with your example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JwEzkl8zxvk6ZX4zLixxuAXNYtgRomtQeh1mFJou73s/edit?usp=sharing.

In sheet3, the name of the sheet (customer1 or customer2) is harcoded in the formula column C. How to dynamise it?

Comment: I adjusted the answer a bit so it might be more directly applicable. I think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks much better but still an error. The value of the parameter 1 of the function INDIRECT is Customer1!$C$2:$C$2000=$A3. This reference of cell/pCette référence de cellule/range is not valid. However, this is exactly the right formula as I can copy/past it in another cell and it works.

Comment: I threw some examples in there to see what broke at what level. It's interesting and the errors might help breakdown the exact issue. I'll revisit when I can but you might have to break the formula into pieces.

Comment: This is fantastic.  I added IFERROR to it - so if the spreadsheet doesn't exist yet, it brings back 0.00.  Works perfectly!